# Cannot change InnerHTML of an item

Tags: javascript

so I am creating a stopwatch and I am almost finished, but I cannot change the innerHTML and reset each area back to 00 when the time is reached.
Here is my code:

```
function init() {
  var myInterval;
  var minutes;
  var seconds;
  var hundredths;
  document.getElementById('btnStart').addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML !== "00") {
      minutes = parseInt(document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML);
    } else {
      minutes = 0;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML !== "00") {
      hundredths = parseInt(document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML);
    } else {
      hundredths = 0;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML !== "00") {
      seconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML);
    } else {
      seconds = 0;
    }
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      hundredths++;
      if (document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML === "59" && document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML === "59" && document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML === "99") {

        stopTime();
      } else {
        if (hundredths >= 10) {
          document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML = hundredths;
        }
        if (hundredths <= 9) {
          document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML = "0" + hundredths;
        }
        if (hundredths > 99) {
          hundredths = 0;
          seconds++;
          if (seconds > 59) {
            seconds = 0;
            hundredths = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes < 10) {
              document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "0" + minutes;
            }
            if (minutes >= 10) {
              document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
            }
          }
          if (seconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
          }
          if (seconds >= 10) {
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
          }

        }
      }
    }, 10);
  });


  document.getElementById('btnStop').addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  });
  document.getElementById('btnReset').addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML = "00";
  });

  function stopTime() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    alert("Cannot Display Past One Hour!");
    console.log(document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML, document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML, document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML === "00";
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML === "00";
    document.getElementById("hundredths").innerHTML === "00";

  }
```

I am having trouble in my stopTime() function towards the bottom.
Anyone know why I can't change the innerHTML?
Here is a video of the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zcm5NrsLEba9ltxlue1PAiXEWC_JwIZg/view

Comment: You have a typo: `== "00"` should be `= "00"`.

Comment: This is not going to work because your timer is set to 10 milliseconds which is faster than the screen can update.  As an alternative, consider using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and using [performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to track elapsed time.